# Unable to get send sudo password to subprocess.Popen() successfully in Python for bash

Tags: python-3.x, bash

I'm attempting to create a python script to compile github surface kernel using their recommended steps. 
https://github.com/dmhacker/arch-linux-surface

So far I'm stuck at a couple of sections.

Per the instructions for compiling the setup.sh must be run using sudo.

I've tried sending in the password before calling process using

```
preproc = subprocess.Popen(password, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", 'sh setup.sh'], shell=True, stdin=preproc.stdout, encoding='utf8')
```

I've tried `sudo -S` which doesn't seem to work at all. I've also tried lowercase `-s`.

I've tried changing `subprocess.Popen` to `subprocess.call`

```
password = getpass.getpass()
process = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", 'sh setup.sh'], shell=True, 
stdin=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf8')
print(process.communicate(password + "\n"))
process.wait()
```

I expected the shell to be run at sudo level but it's not.

Comment: I guess you do not want to disable sudo password for this user? Maybe youcan do this only for this command

Comment: I just looked into that per your suggestion. But It would almost defeat the purpose of the script to have to do manual configuration on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what the difference is as I've since gone through many iterations, but finally got it to work and simplified. Hope this helps someone in the future.

```
import getpass
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
password = getpass.getpass()

command = "./setup.sh"
process = Popen(['sudo', '-S', command], stdout=PIPE, encoding='utf8')
process.communicate(password)
```